# "Each of" with a singular noun. Is semantics of this definition of 'category' appropriate?

Tags: sentence, semantics

> each of a possibly exhaustive set of classes among which all things
>   might be distributed.

I have doubts about "each of a set". Could we use "each of" with singular noun? If so it seems like there are two possible slightly different meaning for "each of" in general, aren't there?

EDIT: Why we can't say "each of a school" as "each student of a school"?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please, check the question now. I'v added an additional question.

Comment: Change it to _each member of a ... set of ..._. Sets have members and the Axiom of Choice allows one to pick each member. Note that this means taking them one at a time, not all together. Where it overlaps with _all_ is the fact that, if this is true of each member of a set, then it is true for all members of the set. _Each, every,_ and _all_ share the same universal quantifier, but differ in details of presupposition and scope.

Comment: It's great, But I don't get why we can't say "each of a school" as "each student of a school". We also can consider a school as a set of different sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each of a possibly exhaustive set

This is an abbreviated way of saying:

*each **member** of a possibly exhaustive set*

Comment: Then why we can't say "each of a school" as "each student of a school"?